# created vue app with pwa, but cannot find manifest.json to edit

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

update: solved by reading document :
https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/pwa.html#configuration

---

I just created a vue app, then 
vue add @vue/pwa

The manifest.json is found by browser, but I can not find the file to edit. Please help!!!!

[the brower shows manifest.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7KZs.png)
[app file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJnBO.png)

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by manually adding a manifest.json file to the public folder. It didn't work at first until I stopped the server and RESTARTED THE SERVER by running npm run serve.